# Passing custom arraylist in aidl(ipc)

Tags: android, ipc, aidl

i am trying to pass a custom arraylist in inter process communication.
i made two aidl files like this

IMyAidlInterface.aidl

```
package com.amaze.DrivePlugin;
import com.amaze.DrivePlugin.Layoutelements;
// Declare any non-default types here with import statements
interface IMyAidlInterface {
    /**
     * Demonstrates some basic types that you can use as parameters
     * and return values in AIDL.
     */
    ArrayList<Layoutelements> list(in String driveID);
}
```

here Layoutelements is a custom class implementing parcelable

Layoutelements.aidl

```
package com.amaze.DrivePlugin;

// Declare any non-default types here with import statements
parcelable Layoutelements;
```

error says "unknown return type arraylist".

i also tried to import arraylist but that didnt helped

Comment: Have you tried using List instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **java.util.List** instead of ArrayList usually solves the problem

Comment: thanks . btw is there any way to throw exceptions too?

Comment: ur welcome :). In the AIDL files , No. But the binders (java classes that implement that aidl generated stubs) can throw any exception, most importantly RemoteException.